# The computer stops working all of a sudden

Tags: sound, keyboard, 20.04, mouse, google-chrome

**Ubuntu version**: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

**Chrome version**: 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Situation**: I am using Chrome and the website that I'm using is [octa.work](https://octa.work), a video-conferencing website. After using the website for more than half an hour (approximately), my monitor froze and speaker started repeating the same thing.
Let's say that someone in the conference said the word *and* before the monitor freezes; my speaker starts repeating the word *and* so many times.
My mouse stops working and there is no mouse light. The keyboard's light is there, but commands aren't doing anything. The only option that I have is to reboot my PC.

This situation has happened more than once. So this doesn't seem like a random event. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

---

The ending part of the output of `journalctl -b -1`:

```
Jul 27 14:34:08 rls-Default-string NetworkManager[727]: <info>  [1595840648.7696] dhcp4 (usb0): state changed bound -> extended
Jul 27 14:34:08 rls-Default-string systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul 27 14:34:08 rls-Default-string dbus-daemon[726]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 27 14:34:08 rls-Default-string systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul 27 14:34:19 rls-Default-string systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Jul 27 14:36:41 rls-Default-string kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (6409 > 6367), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 31000
Jul 27 14:39:41 rls-Default-string gnome-shell[2333]: [2778:16:0727/143941.225239:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3333)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded >
Jul 27 14:39:41 rls-Default-string gnome-shell[2333]: [2778:16:0727/143941.782864:ERROR:dtls_transport.cc(616)] DtlsTransport[0|1|__]: Received non-DTLS packet before >
Jul 27 14:40:10 rls-Default-string gnome-shell[2333]: [2778:16:0727/144010.803437:ERROR:srtp_transport.cc(223)] Failed to unprotect RTP packet: size=1218, seqnum=26824>
```

Output of `free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8Gi       1.8Gi       279Mi       330Mi       1.7Gi       1.4Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        44Mi       2.0Gi
```

Output of `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`:

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Output of `sysctl vm.swappiness`:

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: You'll have to provide some logs for us to diagnose that. Run `journalctl -b -1` to see the system logs from before your reboot and see if there's any obvious error messages.

Comment: Should I provide the entire output of the command? It contains private details like IP address.

Comment: no i wouldn't do that, but can you spot anything in there that looks like it might relate to the crash? It's timestamped, so should be relatively straightforward to find the event

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I've added the ending part of the output. Please check it.

Comment: 3.8 GiB RAM @turbulence

Comment: Please check using System Monitor whether you RAM gets filled up during the video conference.

Comment: Ok. I'll check it. @turbulence

Comment: @heynnema Since I cannot add more RAM, I am not gonna modify the swapfile.

Comment: I understand if you can't add more RAM, but why wouldn't you increase the /swapfile? It'll probably solve your problem.

Comment: @heynnema I'm a very new user of Ubutnu. I'm not interested to modify imprtant system files and mess up. I can't afford to lose data or reinstall Ubuntu. My bad!

Comment: As a new Ubuntu user, I can certainly understand your caution. However, you **did** come here for help, and help is available. The /swapfile being too small is a common problem, even on fresh new Ubuntu installs. In your particular case, the small amount of RAM, only amplifies the problem that you're seeing... hence my answer.

Comment: @heynnema I'm checking if this is the same case with Firefox as well. In case if my PC stops working while using the website in Firefox, I'll try to change the swapfile.

Comment: Chrome can use more RAM/swap than Firefox, so that **may** not be a good test.

Comment: ps: we could still have a further problem if you've installed any GNOME Shell extensions... but we'll check that after the /swapfile increase.

Comment: @heynnema My intention is to check if the issue is system-wide (i.e. in any browser). I've attended the conference twice in Firefox and no issues so far. So this seems like a Chrome-specific issue. So I won't be modifying the swapfile for now. BTW, I don't remember installing any GNOME Shell extensions.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, Chrome uses more memory than Firefox, in most cases. So your lack of RAM and SWAP is your problem. But I'm not going to beg you to fix your system. I'm done.

Comment: @heynnema Ok. Thanks for the information you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

We'll increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: You may need to add more RAM.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

<strike>Add this line to /etc/fstab...</strike>

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```