# Ubuntu is freezing (even in live session)

Tags: live-usb, backup

PC specs:

- RAM: 3.8 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Dual-Core Celeron® N3050 SoC (1.6 GHz)
- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-N3050M-D3P (If I recall correctly)

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS since past couple of months. I've had some freezes in the past (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262398/the-computer-stops-working-all-of-a-sudden)). Since past couple of weeks, Firefox started crashing a lot (but the system didn't freeze).

Lately, the system started freezing even more. Back in those days, PC used to freeze only when I used to multi-task for couple of hours. But now, the system started freezing immediately after launching one or two apps after powering on and logging in. I have no idea what's the reason.

I decided to run `fsck` on my SSD using live session. I tried it and there were no errors. But the PC was still freezing.

So I decided to backup my files using live session. This is where things started getting messy. Now, even the live session started freezing. The only thing I could do if the live session freezes is force restarting the PC by clicking on restart button on CPU. I do acknowledge that force restarting when the live session is running is not a good thing, but I had no other choice. When I tried re-running the live session, one error is found in live session and the live session froze again. I re-made the installation media (formatted it in Windows 10 and then used Rufus again to write the ISO once again). Even this didn't work out.

So I tried live sessions of multiple distros like Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04, Xubuntu 20.04, Linux Mint 20 Xfce (I did verify the download of Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04 and Xubuntu 20.04.). All of them froze at some or the other point (after checking for errors, after entering GUI, or while using some app). I also tried running live session in safe graphics mode, but even that froze.

What might be the issue and how can I fix it?

---

One small thing to note, whenever the PC freezes (either in live session or normal boot from SSD), the mouse light turns off and the keyboard becomes unresponsive.

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`:

[image: Photo of output of lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2]

After adding `iommu=soft` boot parameter and booting the system, this is what happened:

[image: Photo of monitor after booting after adding iommu=soft boot parameter]

Comment: Boot in recovery-mode `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`

Comment: @nobody Added the output. Please check.

Comment: Oh gigabyte. Please try as kernel bootoption `iommu=soft` or `iommu=pt`

Comment: Where should I execute this command? Should I execute it in root shell prompt from recovery menu? @nobody And what should I do after executing this command?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Comment: @nobody I've added details in the question. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116304/discussion-between-nobody-and-technastic-tc).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disk partitions]

I advise you to make a little partition with the format of EFI boot for Ubuntu to install the bootloader on, like the one I have in the picture. It makes things cleaner and better.

Generally, it works. I always have the same problem, but when I do this it prevents most of the crashes and the laptop boots faster and cleaner.

Comment: Do read this message: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56226803#56226803