# How to copy paste files from hardrive having Ubuntu filesystem in Windows using WSL?

Tags: ssd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, transfer

I have a [SSD](https://amzn.eu/d/4v4t9YY) in which I installed Ubuntu 20.04. But I could no longer use the SSD. More details here: [Ubuntu is freezing (even in live session)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1292824)

Now I bought a [SATA to USB A cable](https://amzn.eu/d/hujvMR0). Now, how do I copy paste files from the SSD to my Windows 10 laptop using WSL?

I was trying these instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk

But `wsl --mount <DiskPath>` did not work.

```
Invalid command line option: --mount
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: wsl.exe [Argument] [Options...] [CommandLine]

Arguments for running Linux binaries:

    If no command line is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell.

    --exec, -e <CommandLine>
        Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.

    --
        Pass the remaining command line as is.

Options:
    --cd <Directory>
        Sets the specified directory as the current working directory.
        If ~ is used the Linux user's home path will be used. If the path begins
        with a / character, it will be interpreted as an absolute Linux path.
        Otherwise, the value must be an absolute Windows path.

    --distribution, -d <Distro>
        Run the specified distribution.

    --user, -u <UserName>
        Run as the specified user.

Arguments for managing Windows Subsystem for Linux:

    --help
        Display usage information.

    --install [Options]
        Install additional Windows Subsystem for Linux distributions.
        For a list of valid distributions, use 'wsl --list --online'.

        Options:
            --distribution, -d [Argument]
                Downloads and installs a distribution by name.

                Arguments:
                    A valid distribution name (not case sensitive).

                Examples:
                    wsl --install -d Ubuntu
                    wsl --install --distribution Debian

    --set-default-version <Version>
        Changes the default install version for new distributions.

    --shutdown
        Immediately terminates all running distributions and the WSL 2
        lightweight utility virtual machine.

    --status
        Show the status of Windows Subsystem for Linux.

    --update [Options]
        If no options are specified, the WSL 2 kernel will be updated
        to the latest version.

        Options:
            --rollback
                Revert to the previous version of the WSL 2 kernel.

Arguments for managing distributions in Windows Subsystem for Linux:

    --export <Distro> <FileName>
        Exports the distribution to a tar file.
        The filename can be - for standard output.

    --import <Distro> <InstallLocation> <FileName> [Options]
        Imports the specified tar file as a new distribution.
        The filename can be - for standard input.

        Options:
            --version <Version>
                Specifies the version to use for the new distribution.

    --list, -l [Options]
        Lists distributions.

        Options:
            --all
                List all distributions, including distributions that are
                currently being installed or uninstalled.

            --running
                List only distributions that are currently running.

            --quiet, -q
                Only show distribution names.

            --verbose, -v
                Show detailed information about all distributions.

            --online, -o
                Displays a list of available distributions for install with 'wsl --install'.

    --set-default, -s <Distro>
        Sets the distribution as the default.

    --set-version <Distro> <Version>
        Changes the version of the specified distribution.

    --terminate, -t <Distro>
        Terminates the specified distribution.

    --unregister <Distro>
        Unregisters the distribution and deletes the root filesystem.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time this was written, `--mount` was only available for Windows 11 WSL releases.

Now, with the release of the *application package* version of WSL 1.0.0, this feature comes to updated Windows 10 releases as well.  This requires a Windows 10 with UBR (update build revision) `2311` or later.
This is currently available via the *Option Update* [KB5020030](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/november-15-2022-kb5020030-os-builds-19042-2311-19043-2311-19044-2311-and-19045-2311-preview-237a9048-f853-4e29-a3a2-62efdbea95e2).

You can confirm your UBR from PowerShell with:

```
(Get-ComputerInfo).WindowsUBR
```

Keep in mind that this is only needed for Windows 10.  *All* releases of WSL on Windows 11 support the `--mount` command.

After updating Windows, install the latest Windows Subsystem for Linux application package [from the Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage).  If the Microsoft Store is unavailable to you, use the instructions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1754527/1210833).

After installing the latest WSL, confirm with:

```
wsl --version
```

`wsl --help` should also show the `--mount` option as being available.

Comment: Hyper-V is not available in Windows 10 Home. I used VirtualBox to access the drive. Thanks for answering!